# Setting up distributed erasure code using minio on a local network on premise

Tags: minio, object-storage

I was able to setup non EC mode easily, Now I am trying to setup minio server on local 3 node, as a distributed erasure code mode before I move to setup in the production. I want to replicate this setup in local network.

https://docs.min.io/docs/distributed-minio-quickstart-guide.html

Following the guide link :

I am running this command:

```
zc@rockpix:/minio$ export MINIO_ROOT_USER=minio
zc@rockpix:/minio$ export MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio123#
zc@rockpix:/minio$ minio  server  http://localhost{1...3}/mnt/ssd{1...3}
```

but running the above command result in

```
 Invalid command line arguments: lookup localhost1 on 127.0.0.53:53: server misbehaving
      > Please provide correct combination of local/remote paths
      HINT:
        For more information, please refer to https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-erasure-code-quickstart-guide
```

The guide does not mention if I need to setup a domain name.  I was thinking if the non EC mode can working without a domain setup then why can't we setup distributed erasure code without having domain name setup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message looks like there is a DNS issue with that hostname, use a valid resolvable hostname or IP's.  As a side note four nodes is the minimum recommended for a production setup.